# How to capture linux command log into the file?

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash

Let's say I have the below command.

```
STATE_NOT_C_COUNT=`mongo --host "${DB_HOST}" --port 27017 "${MONGO_DATABASE}" --eval "db.$MONGO_DATABASE.count({\"state\" : {"'"$ne"'":\"C\"},\"physicalTableName\":\"table_name\"},{nolock:true})" | tail -1`
```

When I used to run the above command, got the exception like

**exception: connect failed**

I want to capture this exception in into the file via the error function.

```
 error(){
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
      echo "$1" 2>&1 error_log
          exit 1
    fi       
}
```

I'm using the above function like this:

```
error $STATE_NOT_C_COUNT
```

But I'm not able to capture the exception through the function in files.

Comment: Just direct the script's error output to the file; `exec 2>>error_log` at the top of your script.

Comment: There are more than 400 lines of script and I wanted to capture the exception via log file though the function, basically I will have to use the function for the error handling.

Comment: @tripleee I tried what you have replied, but doesn't work in function, it's only useful for single command.
Note: I am using the variable to store the result.

Comment: No, it's useful for the remainder of the script. But if you only want to redirect a single command's standard error, that's `command 2>>error_log`

Comment: @tripleee You have suggested only to capture the exception in each line of of the code redirecting to the files.

I asked question, how to capture the  exception through the function also I am storing the result in variable.

Comment: What is `echo "$1" 2>&1 error_log` supposed to do?  What it actually does is write the string `"$1 error_log"` to stdout.  Coincidentally, any error message (most likely there are none) is going to be written to stdout as well.  This is almost certainly not what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is terrible.  Let the program that fails print its error messages to stderr, and ensure that stderr is pointed to the right thing.  However, the major issue you are having is just lack of quotes.  Try:

```
error "$STATE_NOT_C_COUNT"
```

The issue is that the command `error $STATE_NOT_C_COUNT` is subject to field splitting, so if $STATE_NOT_C_COUNT contains any whitespace it is split into arguments, and you are only writing the first one.  Another alternative is to write `echo "$@"` in the function, but this will squash whitespace.  However, it cannot be stressed enough that this is a terrible approach, completely against the unix philosophy.  The program should write its error to stderr, and you should let them go there.  Just make sure stderr is pointed where you want it.  The only possible reason to capture stderr is if you want to write it to multiple locations, so you might pipe it to `tee` or to a syslogger, or some other message bus, but doing such a thing is questionable.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned above, but couldn't get the wright answer what I want.

STATE_NOT_C_COUNT=`mongo --host "${DB_HOST}" --port 27017 "${MONGO_DATABASE}" --eval "db.$MONGO_DATABASE.count({\"state\" : {"'"$ne"'":\"C\"},\"physicalTableName\":\"table_name\"},{nolock:true})" | tail -1`


I have used like: 
error "$STATE_NOT_C_COUNT"

but couldn't able to capture the exception in error_log file.

Comment: Very likely the error message printed by mongo is going to its stderr so is not captured in the variable.  That is correct behavior and you ought not try to subvert it.